# Liquidsoap tag encoding

Tags: linux, encoding, debian, icecast, liquidsoap

Good afternoon.

I have a problem with Liquidsoap. It sends cyrillic metadata to Icecast like:
    `&#1040;&#1088;&#1080;&#1103; - &#1064;&#1090;&#1080;&#1083;&#1100;`
Please help me how I can change this encoding?

Best Regards,
Danila.

Comment: I Danila, I wonder why people have been downvoting your question without even daring to comment why. I too am running into problems (although different ones) with Cyrillic handling in liquidsoap. All I can say about your problem is that your metadata is the string "Ария - Штиль" encoded into HTML entities, where each number correspond to the unicode number of the corresponding character. Likely because liquidsoap converts the metadata to ISO-8859-1 (which doesn't represent cyrillic characters) before sending it to icecast. Some players will actually interpret it correctly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `encoding = "UTF-8"` to the parameters of `output.icecast()` !

[Liquidsoap API Reference](http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-svn/reference.html) for `output.icecast()` :

> encoding (string – defaults to ""): Encoding used to send metadata. If empty, defaults to “UTF-8” for “http” protocol and “ISO-8859-1” for “icy” protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Icecast2 to output liquidsoap and was also having garbled output 
ie. `&#1064;&#1091;&#1092;&#1091;&#1090;&#1080;&#1085;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;, &#1058;&#1077;&#1087;&#1087;&#1077;&#1088; &#1057;. - &#1050;&#1086; &#1074;&#1089;&#1077;&#1084; &#1095;&#1077;&#1088;&#1090;&#1103;&#1084;`  when listening on android player but when I added `encoding="ISO-8859-1",` to the parameters of `output.icecast()` I got correctly displayed artist name - song name in Cyrillic ie. `Добронравов Александр - Группа крови`
Hope it helps someone.